# Windows Phone 8.1 Parse - Log in issues

Tags: parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I have been trying to log in to Parse using Windows phone 8.1, I have entered the windows .net key & the application ID but i am getting an error:

"ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The header X-Parse-OS-Version has an empty value."

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?
This is currently the code written

```
public App()
{
this.InitializeComponent();
this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
ParseClient.Initialize("ApplicationID", ".netID");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had to uninstall the  latest version (**1.5.3**) and install the older version

**Install-Package parse -Version 1.5.2**

Still trying to get push to work also but to no success. Sigh